# Tool to batch send files via Gmail

Tags: gmail

I have around 100 files and can only send through Gmail (Dropbox is not an option in this case). Since Gmail and the destination Exchange server both have a file size limitation, I only want to send one file in each email.

Is there a tool that can batch sending files via Gmail?

Comment: Are some of the files larger than the file size limitation?

Comment: Nope, I have already filter out oversized files. If there is any tool that can handle oversized tool, like zipping into several zip files would be even better.

Comment: you will need to write some program. In .net it would be fairly simple to send email, and filter and try to sort out larger files.

Answer (score 1):

First of all note that GMail provides a standard [SMTP server](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=13287) that you can use. Then you just need something that can send emails from the command line over SMTP with attachments. Without having tested it, I think [smtp-cli](http://www.logix.cz/michal/devel/smtp-cli/) could fit the bill nicely.